# Unable to import SimPy

Tags: easy-install, simpy

I am new to SimPy I used the easy_install to install SimPy module then on the command line I simply tried `from SimPy.Simulation import  *` but I get the following error

```
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Aug 22 2011, 14:13:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from SymPy.Simulation import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named SymPy.Simulation
```

I use easy_install to install packages, I have simplejson install without any problem and when I import simplejson I don't get the above error. I did an update and easy_install successfully updated the SymPy module yet I still cant import the SimPy Module

```
[/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages]$easy_install -U SimPy
Searching for SimPy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/SimPy/
Reading http://SimPy.SourceForge.net
Reading http://simpy.sourceforge.net/
Reading https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpy/files/
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/SimPy/simpy.sourceforge.net
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=62366
Best match: SimPy 2.2
Processing SimPy-2.2-py2.6.egg
SimPy 2.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/SimPy-2.2-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for SimPy
Finished processing dependencies for SimPy
```

I also check the `easy-install.pth` file, and looks like everything has been added properly.

```
[/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages]$more easy-install.pth 
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./simplejson-2.1.3-py2.6.egg
./SimPy-2.2-py2.6.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

It will be great if I could get any help on this.

Best;
NH

Comment: Are you trying to import SimPy or SymPy? You used both in the examples you gave. If you're using SymPy, then note that the Python interpreter is case sensitive, and the right package name is "sympy".

Comment: So.. is it `sympy` or `SymPy` or `SimPy` or `simpy`? Because those are all different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`from sympy import *`

http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/tutorial.html#first-steps-with-sympy

Comment: I have already tried that, I posted the question after trying it.